# Session expiration handler using PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

### At this point i am interested to see other techniques on handling session timeouts.

What are some good improvements on this script to detect when a session is no longer valid?

### Important definitions:

> **session.gc_maxlifetime** - *(default 1440 seconds) defines how long an
>   unused PHP session will be kept alive. For example: A user logs in,
>   browses through your application or web site, for hours, for days. No
>   problem. As long as the time between his clicks never exceed 1440
>   seconds. It's a timeout value.*
>
> **session.cookie_lifetime** - *This value (default 0, which means until the browser's next restart) defines how long (in seconds) a session
>   cookie will live. Sounds similar to session.gc_maxlifetime, but
>   it's a completely different approach. This value indirectly defines
>   the "absolute" maximum lifetime of a session, whether the user is
>   active or not. If this value is set to 1*60*60, every session ends after an
>   hour.*

Problems to address:

- Session timeout
- Cookie timeout
- Browser deleted cookies / cleared history

SESSION_handler.php

```
<?php
class SESSION_handler{
public static $gc_maxlifetime;
public static $cookie_lifetime;
function __construct(){
    self::$gc_maxlifetime = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
    self::$cookie_lifetime = ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime');
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}
public function get($session_key){
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        if(!empty($_SESSION[$session_key])){
            $_SESSION['time_at_last_session'] = time();
            return $_SESSION[$session_key];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
public function set($session_key, $session_value){
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        $_SESSION[$session_key] = $session_value;
        $_SESSION['time_at_last_session'] = time();
        return $_SESSION[$session_key];
    }
    return undefined;
}
public function session_expired(){
    if(
        time() - ((!empty($_SESSION['time_at_last_session']))? $_SESSION['time_at_last_session'] : 0) >= self::$gc_maxlifetime ||
        session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ||
        !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])
        ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

is_session_expired.php

```
<?php
    $SESSION = new SESSION_handler();
    if($SESSION->session_expired()){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        (function(){
            tmp_ = arguments.callee;
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/php/is_session_expired.php',
                    success: function(session_expired){
                        if(session_expired == "true"){
                            alert("session has expired");
                        }else{
                            console.log('session has not expired');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        })();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: "If this value [in seconds] is set to 60, every session ends after an hour." ... What? is cookie_timeout in minutes or seconds now?

Comment: After some research, i assume seconds. @Vogel612

Comment: is `$this->time_at_last_session` initialized? I do not see where?

Comment: @Nick it is initialized at $this->time_at_last_session = time(); in the session set method, but i now see a concern for it not being set when in the session_expired method. I have correct that mistake.

Comment: exactly. I do not see any other issue with your code. Do you need the session only for JS and not for PHP ? I could propose an alternative such Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the code works as expected.

One of us for sure made mistake with `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE`. If is me, comment so I can fix the answer.

## Code style

You will have better readability, if you indent everything inside the class.

You need to work on `if` statement in `SESSION_handler::session_expired()`. I can not read it at all. I personally would do it on single row, but then many people will not like it at all.

## Constructor

`self::$cookie_lifetime` - I do not see where you need this?

You initializing the static fields every time.

```
self::$gc_maxlifetime = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
self::$cookie_lifetime = ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime');
```

I would suggest something like this:

```
if (self::$gc_maxlifetime = -1){
   self::$gc_maxlifetime = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
   self::$cookie_lifetime = ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime');
}
```

You also might decide to remove them and use `ini_get` directly. Or you can do static method `SESSION_handler::gc_maxlifetime()`.

Here you create session as well:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Do you really need to check `session_status()`? My experience is you can use `session_start()` directly. If there is a session created, statement will do no harm.

I believe you need to initialize `$_SESSION['time_at_last_session']`, but only if is not set already.

Something like:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['time_at_last_session']))
    $_SESSION['time_at_last_session'] = time();
```

## SESSION_handler::get() and SESSION_handler::set()

Why you have this:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    // ...
}
return undefined;
```

You probably want to check if everything with the session is correct? to do so, use:

```
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    // ...
}
```

You `return undefined;`. This is first time I see this line in PHP. Just remove the `if` statement. Session is already made in constructor. If is not `undefined` will not help at all.

Actually, in constructor, you can `save` the result of `session_start();` into some class property and use it instead of `session_status()`.

## SESSION_handler::session_expired()

should be something like this?

```
public function session_expired(){
    $time = isset($_SESSION['time_at_last_session']) ?
             $_SESSION['time_at_last_session'] : 0;

    // same, but ugly:
    //$time = (int) @$_SESSION['time_at_last_session'];

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        return true; // session problem

    if (time() - $time > self::$gc_maxlifetime)
        return true; // session expired

    // fix $_COOKIE[session_name() thing

    return false; // session is NOT expired
}
```

## is_session_expired.php

All OK if you fix the constructor.